# Is it acceptable to have many 'WHERE' based listeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I'm working on an implementation where I need to listen to effectively the following pseudo-query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'trips' WHERE 'travelers' IS ONE OF [ x,y,z ]
```

Since firebase doesn't allow for OR queries, my current solution is to create all possible permutations of trips x travelers and to listen to all of them.

```js
// Returns an array of {}
const permutations = ( locs, uids ) => {
    let perms = locs.map( location => {
        return uids.map( uid => ( { location: location, uid: uid } ) )
    } )
    return [].concat( ...perms )
}

// Trip destinations
let destinations = [ 'Amsterdam', 'Berlin' ]
// UIDs of travelers (in reality unique hashes)
let uids = [ 'John', 'Mary' ]


// Listeners
return Promise.all( permutations( locations, friends ).map( ( { location, uid } ) => {
        this.db.collection( 'trips' )
        .where( 'destination', '==', location )
        .where( 'traveler.uid', '==', uid )
        .onSnapshot( snapshot => {
            Promise.resolve( snapshot.docs )
            // Filter out empties
            .then( docs => docs.map( doc => doc.exists ? doc : false ) )
            .then( docs => docs.filter( doc => doc != false ) )
            // Grab data from docs
            .then( docs => docs.map( doc => ( { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } ) ) )
            // Call a callback (used int he bigger scheme of a redux listener)
            .then( callback )
        } )
    } ) )
} )
```

Right now this results in a few listeners, but if the destination/uids arrays get big, this could result in MASSIVE amounts of listeners.

I could also run a manual search trigger, but I like working with realtime updates.

Is having potentially a bazillion listeners an issue in firebase? Either for performance or cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to be more specific about "bazillion".  In general, listeners are cheap and you shouldn't worry too much about it.  But everything has a practical limit, and I think you'll discover what that is as you approach your hypothetical "bazillion".

1 listener doesn't invoke billing any different than 10 or 100 or 1000 listeners.  You can expect the billing for a single listener to scale linearly.  Each one will cost exactly what it would normally cost on its own, for each document that is different between all their queries.

Each listner also shares a single connection, so you don't have to worry about running out of open file descriptors or anything like that.  Your limit is, practically speaking, going to be memory and bandwidth.

Comment: That was exactly the info I was looking for. Thanks for explaining the scaling :)

Comment: If you found it helpful, please upvote and accept the answer as correct.